# using jquery closest to select the first <td> value

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am using jquery datatables for html table generation. I setup a callback to create an additional column for links (edit, delete, etc...).

I setup a bind function to detect clicks, which is working.

The problem I am having is selecting the text/value of the first column on the closest row when it is clicked.

Here is the snippet that binds to the class and detects a click.

```
$(".drop").bind('click', function(e)  
{  
   var val = $(e.target).closest('td:first').text();  
   alert(val);                             
});
```

HTML Table Body After Generation

```
<tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>doug@thisisatest.org</td>

                <td>doug@email.com</td>

                <td>1000012342015292781</td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td>cameron@email.com</td>

                <td></td>

                <td></td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td></td>

                <td>jeniper@yay.com</td>

                <td>1734001234268</td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td>test@iaretester.com</td>

                <td></td>

                <td></td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td></td>

                <td>dou@blah.com</td>

                <td>10000201142345292781</td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td>delze@tester.net</td>

                <td></td>

                <td></td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td>boo@boo.com</td>

                <td></td>

                <td></td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td>petroz@ouch.com</td>

                <td>petroz@test.com</td>

                <td>100000723143211905</td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td>helze@arg.com</td>

                <td></td>

                <td></td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td></td>

                <td>cameron@test.com</td>

                <td>8197906212343</td>

                <td><a href="#" class="drop">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you also include an example row from your HTML table?

Comment: What element is the click bound to?

Comment: added the table... Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var val = $(e.target).closest('td').siblings(':first-child').text();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/JZwxD/

Comment: @Peter You didn't even let me post my demo first `:)`

Comment: @Peter Also, note that if you're binding the click handler directly to the ANCHOR element, then you don't need `e.target` ... `this` will work too (as my demo shows).

Comment: Old thread, but I wanted to thank Sime Vidas for the help. The line and fiddle were VERY helpful on my project. Thanks!